# rails: nested resources show.html.erb error: undefined method... nil:nilclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a simple nested resources app but am getting the `undefined method...nil:nilclass` error on the `show.html` from the parent class.  Please help me figure out what is wrong with my code:

*routes.rb:*

```
resources :todo_lists do  
    resources :todo_items #, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]  
end

root 'todo_lists#index'
```

I get an error "no defined method 'todo_items for nil:nilclass' when I run to the bolded line "todo_

*todo_lists.show.html.erb:*

```
 <tbody>
  <% @todolist.todo_items.each do |todo_item| %>
      <tr>
          <td><%= todo_item.title %></td>
      ...
      </tr>
 <% end %>
```

I think it means I did not set the todo_list right somehow but I am not sure where I shall add the code to make this work.  Please help.

Comment: DId you define `@todolist` ? If not, define `@todolist = TodoList.find_by(id: params[:id])` in your `show` action of `TodoLists` controller..

Comment: Thank you Ravi.  That works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `@todo_list` in `show` action of `your  todo_list_controller.rb` like

```
class TooListsController < ApplicationController

  def show
     @todo_list = TodoList.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Comment: Ah, so simple!  Thank you!